# Kibana / Elasticsearch query not returning expected result when using query parameters

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am learning how to use Kibana/Elasticsearch.

Below is a query I am able to run in Kibana/Elasticsearch:

```
GET /my-grain-2021.04.22/_search?q=_id:"e05b6313-294e-____-a726-ff8951a7f958"
```

Result returned:

[image]

As you can see from the above screenshot, `IsDirthy = TRUE` I'm now trying to run the same query but using a different query parameter.

So now I"m trying to run a query that shows documents where that is the case. Below is the query I am trying to use:

```
GET /session-grain-2021.04.22/_search?q=IsDirthy:true
```

[image]

Can someone please tell me why I'm not returning a record for the 2nd query?

Answer (score 0):

In the first query, you are querying against `my-grain-2021.04.22` and in the second query against `session-grain-2021.04.22`. So in both the queries, the index is different.

Maybe you are not having any document in `session-grain-2021.04.22` that have `IsDirthy: true`

Adding a working example with index data, search query, and search result

**Index Data:**

```
{
    "IsDirthy": true
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
GET /index-name/_search?q=IsDirthy:true
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67219577",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.2876821,
        "_source": {
          "IsDirthy": true
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @user9847788 did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :-)